# Razor::InvalidConfigurationError: entry repo_store_root: must be set in the configuration file

Tags: razor, automation, puppet

## Trying to install razor server in ubuntu:12.04, getting error at `rake db:migrate` before `torquebox deploy` and `run`.

stacktrace

```
Razor::InvalidConfigurationError: entry repo_store_root: must be set in the configuration file
             raise_ice at /opt/razor/lib/razor/config.rb:135  validate_repo_store_root at /opt/razor/lib/razor/config.rb:153
             validate! at /opt/razor/lib/razor/config.rb:96
                 Razor at /opt/razor/lib/razor/initialize.rb:80
                (root) at /opt/razor/lib/razor/initialize.rb:19
               require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1084
                (root) at file:/opt/razor-torquebox/jruby/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel19/kernel.rb:1
                (root) at /opt/razor/bin/razor-admin:81
```